# Moment.js locale, format output array

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, datetime, momentjs

I try to use moment.js to display days of this fortnight.

I use the french locale in order to display days like this :

- lundi 13/3 // moment.js format = 'dddd D/M'. Lundi = Monday in french
- mardi 14/3
- etc.

After setting the moment.js locale in the head with

```
<script>
  moment.locale('fr');
</script>
```

The function bellow built an array with the right days (begining on Monday as set in the french locale), but I don't succeed to display this days in the format I want.

```
function thisFortnight() {

    var startFortnight = moment().startOf('week');
    var endFortnight = startFortnight.clone().add(13, 'd');

    var days = []
    var day = startFortnight;

    while (day <= endFortnight) {
        days.push(day.toDate());
        day = day.clone().add(1, 'd');
    }

    var eDisplayMoment = document.getElementById('Fortnight');
    eDisplayMoment.innerHTML = days;

}
```

Output :

Mon Mar 13 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET),Tue Mar 14 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET),Wed Mar 15 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET),Thu Mar 16 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET),Fri Mar 17 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET),Sat Mar 18 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET),Sun Mar 19 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET),Mon Mar 20 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET),Tue Mar 21 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET),Wed Mar 22 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET),Thu Mar 23 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET),Fri Mar 24 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET),Sat Mar 25 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET),Sun Mar 26 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)

It should be :
lundi 13/3, mardi 14/3, mercredi 15/3, etc.

I've tried a lot of solutions with .format('dddd D/M'), without success.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`day.toDate()` returns a native JS date, you want to use the moment object so use `day.format('dddd D/M')`.

e.g.

```js
var d = new moment();
console.log(d.format('dddd D/M'))

function thisFortnight() {

    var startFortnight = moment().startOf('week');
    var endFortnight = startFortnight.clone().add(13, 'd');

    var days = []
    var day = startFortnight;

    while (day <= endFortnight) {
        days.push(day.format('dddd D/M'));
        day = day.clone().add(1, 'd');
    }

    var eDisplayMoment = document.getElementById('Fortnight');
    eDisplayMoment.innerHTML = days.join('<br>');

}

window.onload = thisFortnight;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/locale/fr.js"></script>

<div id="Fortnight"></div>
```